# How do I include the Boost library (version 1.58) to Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, boost, linker, codeblocks

I have seen a couple tutorials but they were for older boost versions.

Normally you include an .a or .lib file in the linker settings but I can't find such a file in my boost directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you download the boost library.

Then you build it.

And after that you have your lib folder etc. which you can include.

Just read the [Guide for Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html) or the [Guide for Unix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)